# Check user's Facebook permissions and re-prompt for missing permission

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a website using ASP.net MVC 4 and I can have the users log in with their facebook account, the problem is that if a user denies publish permission I want to check their active permission and a way to re-prompt in case its necessary, I have created this script:

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('checkPerms').onclick = function () {
        checkPermissions();
    };


    var checkPermissions = function () {
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };


</script>
```

It should return the active permissions but I get an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

so I cant check for the user's permission and I am also not sure how to redirect to an action or how to re-prompt for those permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, I had to save the Facebook token and then retrieve it from a view model.

```
FB.init({
            appId: APPID,
            authResponse: {
                accessToken: '@Model.FacebookToken'
            }
        });
```

after this, I had to check if the permission existed; if not, then I request them again like this:

```
 var checkPermissions = function () {
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            var perms = response.data[0];
            // Check for publish_stream permission
            if (perms.publish_stream) {
                console.log('User has permission')
            } else {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    // Request permission
                }, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
            }

        });
    };
```

Comment: You could also wrap your code in a call to `FB.getLoginStatus`, which will provide the access token if the user has granted access.

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

simply means that there is no user in session currently. So, `/me` will fail. You have not mentioned so I'm not sure where exactly you are checking the permissions. But you should check them at that point when a user is in session.

`/me/permissions` is normally used for checking the the publishing permissions, because people skip the this permission many often. So, just before posting you call this and ask for the publishing permission.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helped me look into the FB.init and reached the solution!